# Rewrite url php with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to make my actual url:

```
http://mywebsite.com/portfolio.php?cat=deportes
```

Into:

```
http://mywebsite.com/portfolio/cat/deportes
```

I've been trying some solutions given on here but none of them work. I can actually get rid of the .php, but do I have to change anything in the a hrefs ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^portfolio/cat/(.+) /portfolio.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

starkeen gave you a nice answer. I would suggest to do it for your whole project, not to create rewrite rules for every url you have.

You can have a .htaccess file like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And then to create your logic with php to parse the url itself and call the method / controller or whatever you wish.